# Goroutines, Channels and Deadlock

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

I'm trying to understand more about go's channels and goroutines, so I decided to make a little program that count words from a file, read by a `bufio.NewScanner` object:

```
nCPUs := flag.Int("cpu", 2, "number of CPUs to use")
flag.Parse()
runtime.GOMAXPROCS(*nCPUs)    

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
lines := make(chan string)
results := make(chan int)

for i := 0; i < *nCPUs; i++ {
    go func() {
        for line := range lines {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", line)
            results <- len(strings.Split(line, " "))
        }
    }()
}

for scanner.Scan(){
    lines <- scanner.Text()
}
close(lines)


acc := 0
for i := range results {
      acc += i
 }

fmt.Printf("%d\n", acc)
```

Now, in most examples I've found so far both the `lines` and `results` channels would be buffered, such as `make(chan int, NUMBER_OF_LINES_IN_FILE)`. Still, after running this code, my program exists with a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` error message.

Basically my thought it's that I need two channels: one to communicate to the goroutine the lines from the file (as it can be of any size, I don't like to think that I need to inform the size in the `make(chan)` function call. The other channel would collect the results from the goroutine and in the main function I would use it to e.g. calculate an accumulated result.

What should be the best option to program in this manner with goroutines and channels? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @AndrewN has pointed out, the problem is each goroutine gets to the point where it's trying to send to the `results` channel, but those sends will block because the `results` channel is unbuffered and nothing reads from them until the `for i := range results` loop.  You never get to that loop, because you first need to finish the `for scanner.Scan()` loop, which is trying to send all the `line`s down the `lines` channel, which is blocked because the goroutines are never looping back to the `range lines` because they're stuck sending to `results`.

The first thing you might try to do to fix this is to put the `scanner.Scan()` stuff in a goroutine, so that something can start reading off the `results` channel right away.  However, the next problem you'll have is knowing when to end the `for i := range results` loop.  You want to have something close the `results` channel, but only after the original goroutines are done reading off the `lines` channel.  You could close the `results` channel right after closing the `lines` channel, however I think that might introduce a potential race, so the safest thing to do is also wait for the original two goroutines to be done before closing the `results` channel: ([playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/OnQRT9ie5U)):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"
import "bufio"
import "strings"
import "sync"

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(`
hi mom
hi dad
hi sister
goodbye`))
    lines := make(chan string)
    results := make(chan int)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for line := range lines {
                fmt.Printf("%s\n", line)
                results <- len(strings.Split(line, " "))
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(lines)
        wg.Wait()
        close(results)
    }()

    acc := 0
    for i := range results {
        acc += i
    }

    fmt.Printf("%d\n", acc)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Channels in go are unbuffered by [default](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types), which means that none of the anonymous goroutines you spawn can send to the **results** channel until you start trying to receive from that channel. That doesn't start executing in the main program until **scanner.Scan()** is done filling up the **line** channel...which it's blocked from doing until your anonymous functions can send to the **results** channel and restart their loops. Deadlock.

The other problem in your code, even when trivially fixing the above by buffering the channels, is that **for i := range results** will also deadlock once there are no more results being fed into it, since the channel hasn't been closed.

Edit: Here's one potential [solution](http://play.golang.org/p/UAH5aW_4hQ), if you want to *avoid* buffered channels. Basically, the first issue is avoided by performing the send to the **results** channel via a new goroutine, allowing the lines loop to complete. The second issue (not knowing when to stop reading a channel) is avoided by counting the goroutines as they are created and explicitly closing down the channel when every goroutine is accounted for. It's probably better to do something similar with waitgroups, but this is just a very fast way to show how to do this unbuffered.